# What does this mean? int i = (i = 20);

Tags: c#

I stumbled across this while starting to learn about vars here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx

However, I have no idea how that is a legal expression (it is). I thought you couldn't assign to something using an a = (b=c) because (b=c) does not produce a value to assign?

Thanks for any clarification on the matter.

Comment: It's a fairly common mistake in `if` statements. `a=10` instead of `a==10`

Comment: @Ben Brocka But int i = (i == 20) wouldn't compile as you are trying to assign a boolean value to an integer.

Comment: The title is misleading. Does someone want to change it? While foo = (bar = baz) is perfectly normal, foo = (foo = bar) would be redundant.

Comment: @Walkerneo: The example in the title is lifted directly from the linked MSDN article.  3rd bullet point in the Remarks section.

Comment: @SeanU, I'm confused by that. Why would anyone do it?

Comment: It's not something anyone is supposed to do.  It's just an example to illustrate one of the rules of the programming language.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is legal.  From the [= operator C# reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx):

> The assignment operator (=) stores the value of its right-hand operand in the storage location, property, or indexer denoted by its left-hand operand and **returns the value as its result.**

(emphasis mine)

The code in the example is contrived (and pointless), but it can be used in other cases to do useful things in a more concise way.  For example:

```
BinaryTree tree;
TreeNode node;
if((node = tree.FindNodeForKey(10)) != null)
{
    // do useful things with returned node
}
```

Comment: You can also use it if you will assign the same value in different variables, like `btnX.Visible = btnY.Visible = btnZ.Visible = false;`, although it is not that readable _(at least for me)_.

Comment: I'd still rather write `TreeNode node = tree.FindNodeForKey(10); if (node != null) {}`.

Comment: @Malcolm: I tend to favor the same in practice.  The only place I really prefer it is in `while` loops. There it helps to avoid having to have two lines of code for assigning to the loop variable - one before the loop, and one at its end.  Probably that would have been a better example.  Oh well.

Answer (score 14):

The whole quote from MSDN is:

> Variables declared by using var cannot be used in the initialization expression. In other words, this expression is legal: int i = (i = 20); but this expression produces a compile-time error: var i = (i = 20);

The point is that you can't use variables declared by var in the initialization expression. In other words, if you use var to declare i, then you can't use i on the other side of the = sign.

As others have noted, you would not actually write this code. This is a contrived example.

Answer (score 6):

I use that kind of thing all the time.

```
public class Parameters
{
    public readonly bool ContainsSquareBrackets;

    public Parameters(string paras)
    {
        if(ContainsSquareBrackets = paras.Contains(']') || paras.Contains('['))
        {
             // do something ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is entirely different from what the question is asking. Logical operators return `true/false`. OP wants to know if `(i=20)` returns a value.

Comment: My expression (variable = bool) is the exact same thing, because the variable returns bool.

Comment: Oh, you're right. My bad. Its an interesting use now that I see it. (Downvote undone)

Answer (score 4):

This particular code is pointless.  The assignment expression returns the value that was just assigned.  Therefore, the result of:

```
i = 20
```

Is, of course, `20`.  Thus:

```
i = (i = 20);
```

Is the same as:

```
i = 20;
```

Occasionally the fact that an assignment returns something can be useful, such as in for loops:

```
for (string line; (line = reader.ReadLine()) != null;) { ... }
```

(For what it's worth, I wouldn't use this idiom in this particular situation)

Or assigning the same value to multiple variables:

```
int x, y;
x = y = 5;
```

Now, both `x` and `y` have the value `5`.

Answer (score 2):

The code is non-thread safe way to assign the literal value 20 to a local variable i.

The expression `i = 20` has the side affect of assigning 20 to `i`, and has the value of `i` after the assignment.  The expression `i = (i = 20)` assigns i the values of `(i = 20)`, which is almost always just the value that `i` has at the time of the outer assignment.  If the thread is interrupted, the expression (i = 20) will still have the value 20, although i may have a different value at the point the outer assignment takes place.

There is no situation in which you would want to write this exact code.

Comment: I'm not sure what thread safety has to do with this, or what is meant by "which is almost always the value of `i`". The expression `i = (i = 20)` will assign 20 to `i`. Regardless of what `i` was to start with.

Comment: If the code is not optimized and the OS interrupts between the two assignments, the final result of i could be something other than 20.  

When I said "which is almost always just the value of i", I meant, "which is almost always the value that i has at the time of the outer assignment."  If the thread is interrupted, the expression (i = 20) will still have the value 20, although i may have a different value at the point the outer assignment takes place.

Comment: I just added that to the answer.

Comment: if you have another thread writing to `i` in such a race, the same situation exists even for a simple `i = 20` - the value of `i` might or might not be `20` depending on when the racing thread happened to do its assignment.  An "outer" assignment really doesn't change that problem for better or for worse.

Answer (score 2):

It is legal in C# because [the order of evaluation for operators is left to right](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/08/14/4374222.aspx) by default,unlike C/C++ languages that don't define a limit in [sequence point.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point). The `=` operator assign the value to 20 and returns the value as result. It's parsed as:

```
int i; //<- i is declared. 
i = 20; // assign 20 to i variable and returns.
i = i; // assign i as i value of.
```

It's an [ambiguous expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hz1ky25.aspx)

Comment: `int i = (i = 20);` is **not** undefined behavior in C/C++

Answer (score 1):

While it means the same as `i = 20`, it might have a useful purpose in certain situations.

If someone else will maintain your code, and sees something like this:

```
if ( i = some_function() )
```

they might think it is a mistake and relpace `=` with `==`.
To signal that this is what you intended to do, you can use

```
if ( i = (i = some_function()) )
```

However, I personally find `if ( i = /* = */ some_function() )` or just `i = some_function(); if (i)` to be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Even the following is valid too in C++ and C# both:

int i = i = i = 20;

The statement above is a simple use of assignment operator assigning valves from right to left operand.

Answer (score 0):

You can do same approach, on how to declare a variable.. it just the one you read make it complicated to read.

It is exists because it can be used to obfuscate code in my opinion its presence had a deep connection to security..

Answer (score 0):

The assignment operator returns the value assigned.

Thus,

```
i = 20
```

returns 20

which gets assigned to i.

So,

```
i = (i = 20);
```

is as good as

```
i = 20;
```