# Is it undefined behavior to initialize a variable with a value returned by an expression that assigns a value?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

Is the below code undefined by the standard?

```cpp
int fingers = 10;
int more = (fingers = 10);
// or 
// int more = fingers = 10;
```

Is the answer to the above also applicable to an `std::map`?

```cpp
std::map<int, int> arms;
int bicep = (arms[200] = 10);
```

Comment: Why do you suspect it might be UB?

Comment: Why would `int fingers = 10; int more = (fingers = 10);` be UB? The assignment operator returns the left hand operand by reference.

Comment: Similar to C# [What does this mean? int i = (i = 20);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610561/what-does-this-mean-int-i-i-20)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the below code undefined by the standard?

No, the code is **well-formed**. The **built-in assignment** `operator=` **returns the left hand operand by reference which is then used as an initializer for** `more`.

---

> Is the same answer to the above applicable to an std::map?

Yes, here also the assignment operator return the left hand operand which is of type `int` by reference which is then used as an initializer for `bicep`.

Answer (score 2):

1. No, this isn't undefined behavior. When you set a variable to a value, that value is returned in the expression.
2. Yes, it works with maps as with variables.

Answer (score 1):

The `=` is an operator just like other operators.  Like other operators, it has a well defined return value - the value it just assigned.  There's nothing undefined in your code.